# How to remove previous merges and commits from the pull request on a feature branch?

Tags: git, github

Somewhere a month ago, I've started to have extra commits and merges with every pull request I make. The `git log` command shows all those commits as well.

Most of the answers I've seen here was related to the develop branch cleanup, but it seems like something happened to my local git history.

What can I do to see only those commits that are related to the feature I'm working on?

Example of commits and merges unrelated to the branch, I'm working on:
[image: Example of commits and merges unrelated to the branch, I'm working on.]

Comment: Before pushing and posting the pull request, are you remembering to pull develop and rebase the feature branch onto it?

Comment: Yes sure, rebasing now, just to be sure, but usually I do pull + creating feature from the develop.

Comment: “pull + creating feature from the develop” Yes, that is how you _start_ a feature branch. But I am asking about how you _end_ a feature branch.

Comment: Another question. After pull request and merge do you destroy the feature branch? If not, that’s the problem. You are reusing an old merged branch. Don’t do that. Merge, pull, delete, start afresh.

Comment: Before closing it, i pull develop and merge it into the feature(resolving conflicts if necessary), next I squash and merge the result into develop and delete the branch.

Comment: If you rebase instead of merge, you won’t see those merge commits.

Comment: Oh thank you, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are having difficulty with the problem of a long-lived branch.

Let's say your team merges to `develop` and you always work on a feature branch. Let's call it `feature`. If you create `feature` and start working and keep working, meanwhile `develop` may advance, and you will miss those advances. Conflicts with `develop` may be created, which can be annoying when the time comes to merge later, and even worse, you're not using the "latest and greatest" code in your own branch.

What's the solution? It appears that *your* solution is, occasionally, to get onto `develop`, pull, then get onto `feature` and merge `develop` onto it.

That's not wrong per se, but there's a problem: it leaves a merge commit every time you do that. And that, it seems, is what you are complaining about.

Instead, from time to time, get onto `develop`, pull, then get onto `feature` and *rebase* onto `develop`. This will cause it to appear that `feature` started right at the end of where `develop` is now.

Do that one from time to time as you work, and do it one last time just before you push. Then quickly clean up `feature` (I usually completely rewrite all the commits to be more compact and informative), push, and create the pull request.

Comment: Thank you for this option, however it didn't work for me. The merges didn't disappear, but that is half of the problem. When I did pull on the develop branch and rebase on the feature it actually conflicted with my previous commits! That was extremely strange. All my files from yesterday's commits conflicted with what I've done today, yet all the commits from develop were applied. I'm not sure what else I can do now, probably just clone the project again, and start over...

Comment: You don't want to rebase develop onto feature, you want to rebase feature onto develop. And when you do, yes there can be conflicts, but that's not a problem, you just resolve them.

Comment: Yes, what I mean I used rebase develop inside my feature branch, correct? But conflicts was with my previous commits in the current branch, you see :) 
So after I call rebase develop - I have conflicts inside feature branch with feature branch. 
Incredible issue, I understand, but probably there is something tiny that I'm missing.